# Yup - Output a field value in the error message

Tags: javascript, yup

I am trying to output the field value in the error messaging doing something like this:

```
const schema = commonSchema.concat(Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup
    .string()
    .oneOf(
      [Yup.ref('oldName'), null],
      `Name must match oldName - ${Yup.ref('oldName').getValue()}`
    )
    .required('name'),
}));
```

This is giving TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined. What is the right way to access the field value in an error message?

Answer (score 3):

The trick I use to get the value into error message is to use yup.lazy method.

```
yup.lazy((value: any) => Schema): Lazy
```

In your case it would look something like this,

```
const schema = commonSchema.concat(Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.lazy((value) => 
    Yup.string()
    .oneOf(
      [Yup.ref('oldName'), null],
      `Name must match oldName - ${value}`
    )
    .required('name')),
}));
```

Comment: this gives value of `name` not the value of `oldname`. quetion says he requires value of `oldname`. I am also stuck on this question